# Mysql: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql

I know, it's really sad, but I'm not able to connect to MySQL database.

I simply donwloaded and unzipped mysql-5.6.10-win32.zip from MySQL site.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/MySQL_HowTo.html), but I'm not able to connect to my MySQL database as root.

I know it's not secure to connect as a root without the password, but I just need to do some test, so it's ok for me to do it now (and if I know how to connect as a root I know how to add another user too).

## my.ini

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
basedir=c:\Programs\mysql-5.6.10-win32
datadir=c:\Programs\mysql-5.6.10-win32\data
port=3306
server_id=1


# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES 

[client]

port=3306
```

When I start `mysqld` I see:

```
> mysqld --console --init-file=..\set_root_password.sql
2013-04-02 13:48:24 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] InnoDB: CPU does not support crc32 instructions
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] InnoDB: 1.2.10 started; log sequence number 1626183
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] Execution of init_file '..\set_root_password.sql' started.
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] Execution of init_file '..\set_root_password.sql' ended.
2013-04-02 13:48:24 8600 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.10'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

`set_root_password.sql` contains some commands I found in [How to reset root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html), and few others I hoped they help:

```sql
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('pass') WHERE User='root';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root@localhost';

SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'%';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

but I'm not able to login still.

To login I tried:

```
>mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

>mysql -u root --password=pass
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

>mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

>mysql -u root --password=
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

>mysql -u root --password=mysql
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

>mysql -u root mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

>mysqladmin --no-defaults -u root version
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

In some tutorial I read about `mysqladmin` command but it requires root password too.

I tried also empty password and mysql as default password and nothing wokrd.

I tried also `--skip-grant-tables` without success.

I do not have mysqld_safe in bin directory of MySQL home directory, so I couldn't try that.

I tried to read all questions here related to that issue, but I have no idea what I can try to yet...

I'm frustrated why it isn't as simple as "download & run". I do not want to download Win installer, because I do not want services started on Windows startup and other stuff copied in my system without control...

Comment: If its a fresh installation like you mentioned, then what forbids you from adding a temporary password to root even if you don't want a permanent one

Comment: Try `mysql_secure_installation` from terminal.

Comment: I have to ask, by what command are you trying to login ;-)?

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ I do not understand what you are suggesting, please describe what you mean and I'll try it

@hjpotter92 There is some file called `mysql_secure_installation.pl`, but I do not know how to use it

@Najzero I'll add it to question, good point thanks

Comment: @Betlista could you please try `mysql -u root mysql` as root should not have a password on a fresh installation ( security risk ). To bypass might used options, you can try `mysqladmin --no-defaults -u root version` too

Comment: @Najzero I added those to question (last two)

Comment: This is not a valid solution for MySql 8.0, because they no longer use ini files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found, that I have to connect specifying -h and my PC name from `ipconfig -all`

```
>ipconfig -all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : PC1234
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : tmdev
```

and

```
mysql -u root -h PC1234 --password=pass
```

works fine. Thanks for help. It's strange, but it's working now.

**edit:**

I had problems to connect with that configuration. I solved it by specifying `bind-address` in my.ini:

```
bind-address=localhost
```